# Not able to connect to maria db from spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, database-administration

I generated a spring boot project from start.spring.io, but I cannot configure my datasource connection.

```
java.sql.InvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Could not connect to address=(host=192.168.1.25)(port=3306)(type=master) : Access Denied to user
```

Comment: *"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"*. Not just the name of the technologies you're using. Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @adiga am not able to connect to maria DB

Comment: Can you connect to the same database, with the same credentials, on the same host and port, from your MySQL Admin Tool?  That error is telling you that you have invalid credentials - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException.html.